# flutter initState with MediaQuery.of(context)

Tags: flutter

I would like to initialize some of the widgets with the `size` and `width` of the screen.

When I try to use the `initState` method like

```
double anyvariable = 30.0;
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var windowwidth     = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    setState(() {
      anyvariable       = _mediaQueryData.size.width/2;
    });
 }
```

I receive the error

```dart
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before
_CustomWidgetState.initState() completed. ...
```

How do I fix this error or how to I init the widgets with information about the width and height of the screen available before build?

Comment: Start in [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html). `It is safe to call BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType from this method`, but beware that didChangeDependencies is called whenever the Object State changes.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `setState` inside `initState`, with is not a good practice and can also give you the error you're facing.

To solve this, you can write this way.

**1. You can wrap the code with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`:**

```
double anyvariable = 30.0;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {

       var windowwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

       setState(() {
           anyvariable = _mediaQueryData.size.width/2;
        });

     });

 }
```

Comment: This is working fine, but the widget still seems to be initialized with ```double anyvariable = 30.0;``` and then jumps to the value given in initState variable.

Comment: Yes, because you write this that way, first time it 30 & when the initState call then you setting the new value using setState;